# Count PI with analytical methods

Tags: analysis, geometry

Is there a differential equation which can be used to count the value of pi?

*I was able to describe pi only with sequences based on polygons with infinite corners. I think I'll need a continuous variable to describe it with a differential equation, but the number of the corners can be only integer...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\pi$ is the smallest strictly positive root of the unique solution of the ivp
$$y''+y=0,$$
$$y(0)=0,$$
$$y'(0)=1.$$

But as practical method for approximating $\pi$ is lousy. There are much better methods: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiFormulas.html.